# Real Time Replication Between Two Different Schemas in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I have a client who has a legacy application that will partly be replaced by a new application, both use SQL Server 2008 R2 databases with similar, but different schemas. The new database is a super set of the old databases with tables both consolidated and broken out for better normalization.

While eventually the new application will completely replace the old application they will be existing in parallel for some time, and the data entered in one needs to be reflected in the other in near-real time. Is there any product or, even better, MS package that would support something like Replication + SSIS?

The solution we've come up with right now is implementing triggers in the old database that write to the new database and implementing replication to the old database in the data layer (C#/.NET if anyone cares). It is not possible, for both technical and political reasons, for us to modify the old application (Cold Fusion) to do the same. While this solution works it is obviously ugly and we'd like something more elegant if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: We have systems with trigger/log based replication and it isn't ugly it works fine. Given your constraints it sounds like the best solution. Personally I wouldn't use C# to transfer data I'd use SSIS but it's really down to your teams skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you've got (triggers) is probably as good a solution as any. I don't think you'll be likely to find an off-the-shelf solution, simply given the nature of the variance in a normalization process.

You might be able to accomplish something clever using [merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx).

Perhaps you could actually use an identical data model in your new database, and establish merge replication. Then create views, and attach some `instead of` triggers to them, to simulate the new table structure. (Or, do it exactly backward - replicate the new model to the old database, and use views + triggers to simulate the old data model to the old application.)

However, the single best option, in this case, is probably to create an SSIS package. This is really the sort of problem that SSIS was designed to handle, after all.